# Why is my <span> being removed when i try to create a node in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create an HTML paragraph tag in my modal box through DOM Nodes in Javascript. This works but every time the name gets added, the H2 element from the HTML page gets removed. I have no idea why.

I've tried changing the tag name to see if it would make a difference and I've also tried appending them to separate variables in order to just display it but nothing seems to work and I'm trying to avoid hard-coding this in.

When the user clicks on the add to cart option, the Item should get added to the modal box

What's happening is that it gets added to the modal box but the H2 element gets removed from the HTML page.

```js
let modal = document.getElementById("modal-box");
let modalCont = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
let openBtn = document.getElementById("modalOpen");
let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0];

openBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
});

span.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
});

function addCartItems(num) {
  document.getElementById("emptyCart").style.display = "none";
  let pName = document.getElementsByClassName("productName")[num - 1];
  let pPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("price")[num - 1];

  let para = document.createElement("p");
  let statement = document.createTextNode("Quantity");
  modalCont.appendChild(para.appendChild(pName));

}
```

```css
.flex-productContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  height: auto;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  background-color: black;
}

.productContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.categoryHeader {
  height: fit-content;
  color: black;
  background: whitesmoke;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.productCategory {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
}

.ishoe1 {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 300px;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 6%;
  text-align: center;
}

.productButton {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: ease 0.3s;
}

.productButton:hover {
  /*opacity: 0.7;*/
  background-color: #E06688;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.productButton:active {
  background-color: #9a475d;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px #713643;
}

.price {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 300px 250px;
}

.hid-box {
  top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 100%;
}

.box:hover>.hid-box {
  top: 0;
}

.productInfo {
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.box1 {
  background-image: url("../img/badminton/b4.jpg");
}

.box2 {
  background-image: url("../img/badminton/b3.jpg");
}

.box3 {
  background-image: url("../img/badminton/b6.jpg");
}

.box4 {
  background-image: url("../img/basketball/bbRebok1.1.jpg");
}

.box5 {
  background-image: url("../img/basketball/bbmenshoe3.jpg");
}

.box6 {
  background-image: url("../img/basketball/bbmenshoe2.jpg");
}

.showCart {
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}


/*Shopping cart page css*/

.cartHeaderSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 1%;
  height: 10%;
  width: 15%;
  border: black 2px;
  background-color: #E06688;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

.itemEntrySection {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.cart-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-column {
  margin-right: 18%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.modal-box {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

.close-button {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: ease 0.2s;
  user-select: none;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #F4511E;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="productContainer">
    <div class="showCart">
      <button id="modalOpen" class="showCartBtn">SHOW CART</button>
    </div>
    <div class="productCategory">
      <h1 class="categoryHeader">Indoor Sports - Badminton</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box1">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Badminton Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p1" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(1)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box2">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Badminton Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p2" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(2)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box3">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Badminton Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p3" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(3)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="productCategory">
      <h1 class="categoryHeader">Outdoor Sports - Basketball</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box4">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Basketball Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p4" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(4)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box5">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Basketball Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p5" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(5)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box6">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Basketball Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p6" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(6)">ADD to Cart</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="modal-box" class="modal-box">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
      <p id="emptyCart">You have no items in your cart</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/external.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry ... which H2 element exactly? I don't see any in your code

Comment: Apologies I forgot I changed it to a span tag. I've fixed it above

Answer (score 0):

When you call `para.appendChild(pName)` it removes the element from the original position and moves it to new parent instead you can clone it like `para.appendChild(pName.cloneNode(true)`

```js
let modal = document.getElementById("modal-box");
let modalCont = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
let openBtn = document.getElementById("modalOpen");
let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0];

openBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
});

span.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
});

function addCartItems(num) {
  document.getElementById("emptyCart").style.display = "none";
  let pName = document.getElementsByClassName("productName")[num - 1];
  let pPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("price")[num - 1];

  let para = document.createElement("p");
  let statement = document.createTextNode("Quantity");
  modalCont.appendChild(para.appendChild(pName.cloneNode(true)));

}
```

```css
.flex-productContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  height: auto;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  background-color: black;
}

.productContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.categoryHeader {
  height: fit-content;
  color: black;
  background: whitesmoke;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.productCategory {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
}

.ishoe1 {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 300px;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 6%;
  text-align: center;
}

.productButton {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: ease 0.3s;
}

.productButton:hover {
  /*opacity: 0.7;*/
  background-color: #E06688;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.productButton:active {
  background-color: #9a475d;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px #713643;
}

.price {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 300px 250px;
}

.hid-box {
  top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 100%;
}

.box:hover>.hid-box {
  top: 0;
}

.productInfo {
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.box1 {
  background-image: url("../img/badminton/b4.jpg");
}

.box2 {
  background-image: url("../img/badminton/b3.jpg");
}

.box3 {
  background-image: url("../img/badminton/b6.jpg");
}

.box4 {
  background-image: url("../img/basketball/bbRebok1.1.jpg");
}

.box5 {
  background-image: url("../img/basketball/bbmenshoe3.jpg");
}

.box6 {
  background-image: url("../img/basketball/bbmenshoe2.jpg");
}

.showCart {
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}


/*Shopping cart page css*/

.cartHeaderSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 1%;
  height: 10%;
  width: 15%;
  border: black 2px;
  background-color: #E06688;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

.itemEntrySection {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.cart-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-column {
  margin-right: 18%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.modal-box {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

.close-button {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: ease 0.2s;
  user-select: none;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #F4511E;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="productContainer">
    <div class="showCart">
      <button id="modalOpen" class="showCartBtn">SHOW CART</button>
    </div>
    <div class="productCategory">
      <h1 class="categoryHeader">Indoor Sports - Badminton</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box1">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Badminton Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p1" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(1)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box2">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Badminton Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p2" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(2)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box3">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Badminton Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p3" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(3)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="productCategory">
      <h1 class="categoryHeader">Outdoor Sports - Basketball</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box4">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Basketball Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p4" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(4)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box5">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Basketball Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p5" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(5)">ADD to Cart</button>


    </div>

    <div class="ishoe1">
      <div class="box box6">
        <div class="hid-box">
          <p class="productInfo">Flexible,indoor wear,excellent grip , ladies footwear</p>
          <button class="viewProduct">View Product</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="productName">Basketball Shoes</span>
      <p class="price">$63</p>
      <button id="p6" class="productButton" onclick="addCartItems(6)">ADD to Cart</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="modal-box" class="modal-box">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
      <p id="emptyCart">You have no items in your cart</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/external.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay arun but how do i only copy the content rather than the element and its styling. Because the clone function copies the styling as well

Comment: in that case you create a span yourself and just add the content to it

Comment: Actually, shouldn't you just do `para.appendChild(pName.textContent)`? There's no need to create a new span or whatever, because `para` is already a `<p>` tag, so if you wanted to style it you would just style the `<p>` tag.

Comment: @Zeke yes, that is what I was mentioning in my second comment